# WSO2 products performance in real time

Tags: wso2, esb, wso2-cep, wso2-esb

Currently I am keen on finding open source Entity Service Bus(ESB) to build an architecture.I googled on it and found that WSO2 ESB is fine.Among all WSO2 related products only WSO2 ESB product has been bench marked.I dont have idea on remaining product performance.I would like to get suggestions on latest ESB performance in real time world.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since WSO2 has wide range products it would be great if you want could specify what sort of products you are considering. Anyway if we consider about WSO2 DAS, which is the analytic platform consist WSO2 CEP and WSO2 BAM features for real time and batch processing (In near future WSO2 Machine Learner will be added). The performance numbers are extremely good where as WSO2 CEP is capable of processing 100K+ events per second and one of the fastest real time processing engine [1]. Again it was a Finalist for DEBS Grand Challenge 2014 where it was able process 0.8 Million events per second with 4 nodes.[1]

Benchmark results for last release of WSO2 ESB 4.8.1 is available which was done in last year [2]. At the moment WSO2 ESB 4.9.0 release at Beta stage and soon will be officially released and performance benchmark figures will be released.

[1] http://srinathsview.blogspot.com/2015/03/introducing-wso2-analytics-platform.html

[2] http://wso2.com/library/articles/2014/02/esb-performance-round-7.5/

Comment: Thanks for the reply tharik. I have already seen WSO2 ESB performance.I wanted to know others products as well(like WSO2 BPS,WSO2 CEP,WSO2 UEP, WSO2 carbon, WSO2 activity monitor) in real time and also I have seen all reputation in their sites only not from out side world. so that i cant take a decision whether i could go ahead with that or not.please suggest me further about their products in real time.

Comment: You can get a clue by referring WSO2 case studies [1] of real world scenarios. Since WSO2 products are open source and free you have complete freedom to download binaries or even the source code and do actual performance testings or functionality testings and get a good idea without relying on the benchmarks or feed backs provided by some other. 

[1] http://wso2.com/casestudies